# Standard input in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I made a usaco program in c++, and I was trying to debug it. however, I was trying to put in standard input (I commented out the freopen), but I can't figure out where to type it. I got frustrated and now Im confused. Any help would be great, thank you!

I was trying to find a way to type input. I enabled the settings in run code configurations, but it still won't work.

EDIT: I am using c++ to write my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your code from the terminal instead. This will give you access, directly, to a terminal where you can type stdin. You can open a new one in Visual Studio Code from Terminal - New Terminal. From the terminal it depends what language you were programming in.

If you have an input "file", you can use redirection from the terminal to push that file into your program. There are a lot of options depending on what you're actually doing. If you have an executable named a you might write:

```
"./a < inputfile.dat"
```

You can also try "ctrl-shift-d" and then select run and debug which should give you access to stdin in the terminal

Comment: So how should I run the program? Should I just press the button the top right?

Comment: First, what language are you developing in?

Comment: If python, just type python followed by your py file name. So if you're writing in test.py try: `python test.py` in the terminal. You should be in the proper directories by default.

Comment: You can also try "ctrl-shift-d" and then select run and debug which should give you access to stdin in the terminal